# Collect all the [gems]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

All the Ruby Gems are currently fairly evenly split over two tags:

- [rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubygems)
- [gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gem) (with synonym [gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gems))

The synonym is already proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rubygems/synonyms

(The other synonym-suggestion, for [ruby-on-rails-gems] was [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6528355) from long ago, also the tag no longer exists, so consider downvoting *that* synonym)

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528355/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-ruby-on-rails-gem the community decided that there isn't such a thing as a "ruby on rails gem", and therefore the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: That doesn't look like a meta question. It's asking if a certain programming concept exists, which it does not. The discovery, and subsequent removal, of the tags are just asides. That being said, since @AndrewGrimm is here Andrew would you like your question removed?

Comment: Do you mean to tell that we have to *Stop collecting [gems]* once it is made a synonym?  ;_;